# Merging a modified file from one branch, to another branch with additional commits Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to merge some changes made to a particular file (GitBasics.docx shown by change 2), to another branch.

Below are the three recent commits from branch `develop` (contains the file to which I made changes):

```
commit c5fab21e2837808fbc1a4d351b9d605ae856477e
Author: <>
Date:   Tue Jul 10 17:25:40 2018 +0530

    change 3

commit 872926a8a356183e46d281a14578f3895438ae72
Author: <>
Date:   Mon Jul 9 12:58:33 2018 +0530

    change 2 (made to Git Basics.docx)

commit 25ce9bcf0b2c44e29e148d11ea89df508758d014
Author: <>
Date:   Thu Jul 5 20:22:21 2018 +0530

    change 1
```

And below are the two recent commits from branch `test` (to which I've made additional changes):

```
commit c9f0ef332e1f5e9f398179372222d2ac5580ee96
Author: <>
Date:   Fri Jul 6 19:41:55 2018 +0530

    change 4

commit 25ce9bcf0b2c44e29e148d11ea89df508758d014
Author: <>
Date:   Thu Jul 5 20:22:21 2018 +0530

    change 1
```

As you can probably see, change 1 is where I created branch `test`. I would like to merge change 2 from `develop` to `test`. I won't be able to use `git merge` because `develop` also has additional commits (change 4) different from `test` and I do not want them merged.

By doing some research I came across the command `git checkout source_branch <paths>` which serves my purpose currently but I also learned that this method is simply replacing the file in the new branch, instead of merging. Hence if changes (to the same file) were made on both branches, I would lose them on the branch the file was being copied to.

The other option I believe is `git cherry-pick` but frankly I am unable to understand how to use this command from the information given online. How can I use this command, or are there any other ways to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

**I was referring to http://schacon.github.io/git/git-cherry-pick.html for info on `git cherry-pick`, I didn't think the provided solution would be so simple. I am sharing the link in case it helps anybody else.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As question was changed so changed the answer. Use:

```
git checkout test
git cherry-pick 872926a8a
```

This will create copy of 872926a8a commit (change 2) in branch test.

Comment: Except they specifically said it's not good enough, and specifically said why.

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger, you know there is no problem in merging two branches with different commits, but looks like Abd Maj do not know this.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thank you Mark for pointing that out. However, upon review of my question, I realized that I mixed up the branch names. It should read "I won't be able to use git merge because 'develop' also has additional commits different from 'test'" and not the other way round. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: @ephemerr You are right, I was responding to Mark before I could get back to you. I will edit the question, you can see where I went wrong in my comment to Mark.

Comment: @Abd Maj so you do not want all changes of `develop` in your `test` but only some of them? In your description there is only one commit in `develop` and one commit in `test`, that differs.

Comment: @ephemerr I've modified the question to remove the current confusion. I only want change 2 from `develop` merged with `temp`. Please note that I don't want to use `git checkout source_branch <paths>` since it is simply replacing the existing file in `temp`. I want you to consider a situation where the same file is modified in `temp` and we want a merge, not a replacement.